# Constructing a 15+ vertex graph with specific conditions.

Tags: graph-theory

I have been playing around for hours trying to make a graph with 15 or more vertices that satisfies these specific conditions (for my graph theory homework).

1) Minimum degree of among all the vertices in the graph is 3.

2)is 2-connected (the removal of 2 vertices disconnects the graph).

3)is eulerian (contains a cycle that contains every edge of the graph).

4) is non hamiltonian (does not contain a cycle that contains every vertex of the graph).

5) is planar

Im so stuck on this and have been playing around with creating one for hours. Anyone know?

Comment: N.B. Those aren't quite the right definitions for Eulerian and Hamiltonian.

Comment: N.B. 2-connected means that the removal of 1 vertex does not disconnect the graph

Comment: If the minimum degree equals 3, you cannot have an Eulerian circle, only an Eulerian path

Comment: Then are you saying it is impossible to make one with these given conditions?